# Azure B2C - using Graph API to register users instead of using user flows / custom policies

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

The standard way of allowing users to register/sign up to using a B2C user account is via a user flow or custom policy.

Instead of this, we are contemplating instead to build a bespoke application that we take the user through a process to create their account, and make calls via the Graph API in order to create their user account in B2C.

When it then comes to the user then signing in / changing their password, we would then use custom policies to do this. The bespoke process would just be for when they register.

The main reason for thinking about this process is because we have a lot of business logic we need to include in the process and want to break the sign up process into a number of steps. Trying to incorporate this into custom policies with calls to web api endpoints is tricky.

Any suggestions on whether this approach is reasonable, or should this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Cons:

- After sign up, users have to sign in again, poor UX
- After sign up, sign in may not work for a few seconds or more due to replication delay
- You can’t enrol into Azure MFA at sign up
- You can’t perform email verification at sign up

Pros:

- You can make your own UI easier than with B2C policy